# Accessing static file images through url not working django

Tags: python, django, image, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to configure my django project so that I can access static file images via url. However, it is currentely saying that the image does no exist.

Here are my settings for static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/images')
```

Here are my base project urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And my folder structure is, in the root of my project: static->images->[all images in here]

Upon trying to access an image via url like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/*proper image name*
It tells me that the image doesn't exist. Here is the call back:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/IMG_4622_2.JPG
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
'IMG_4622_2.JPG' could not be found

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_URL specifies the url path to serve static files. In your case the setting points to `/static/`.

So that's where you have to access them - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/*proper image name*`

Comment: That didn't work either. It still says *image name* can't be found. I put the full call back in the original question

Comment: @Been-H, overlooked that you have your files in an images folder. You need to write your full path starting at /static/ (in your case http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/*proper image name*)

Comment: That's what I tried above and it still doesn't work. This is what I put http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/*image name*